# Inserting an AVPlayerLayer below GLKView Layer

Tags: ios, opengl-es

All I am trying to accomplish is to place an `AVPlayerLayer` behind an active OpenGL layer.

I am using a `GLKViewController` (with respective `GLKView`). I load a video with `AVPlayer` and establish a corresponding `AVPlayerLayer`. Both my GL Layer and `AVPlayerLayer` appear, however, regardless of what form of "insert sublayer" I call (above, below, at index, etc.), the GL Layer always appears behind the `AVPlayerLayer`.

```
_videoData = playerItem;
_videoPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:_videoData];
_playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_videoPlayer];

_playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(250, 250, 300, 300);  
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:_playerLayer below:self.view.layer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by inserted a GLKViewController as a child of a UIView with the video player. After much experimentation it appears you cannot place anything (subviews or layers) behind the GL layer when using GLKViewController independently.